# How to specify correctly wsgi for Heroku deploy?

Tags: django, heroku, procfile

I have following project structure
[image]

In Procfile i difine web as `web: gunicorn george_paintings.wsgi`
When i deploy project on Heroku i see that Heroku identified my Procfile

```
Starting process with command `gunicorn george_paintings.wsgi`
```

But when i got an error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'george_paintings'`
`
How to properly set up wsgi in Proclife in context of my project structure?

Comment: Looks like you have one extra nesting. Did you try with `gunicorn george_paintings.george_paintings.wsgi`??

Comment: @gdef_ Thank you for your answer. I tried and got  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'george_paintings'

Comment: Is there a reason you have the extra `application` folder. Usually the `Procfile`, `requirements.txt`, etc are in the same level as `static`, `manage.py`, etc. I think your error can be fixed adding an empty `__init__.py` file in your outer `george_paintings` folder. But I recommend that you move what's outside to that folder instead

Answer (score 1):

Your `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ...` error is generally fixed by adding an empty `__init__.py` file to the folder. See [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages)

> The **init**.py files are required to make Python treat directories containing the file as packages

What I would suggest is to remove the `application` folder and move `Procfile`, `README.md` and `requirements.txt` to the outer `george_paintings` and use that as your root folder.

Then `web: gunicorn george_paintings.wsgi` should work as expected.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But in my case, i need an application folder since i am planning to do angular front end in client folder, so i wanna separate backend from from frontend